# User.history and actual message send

Tags: gmail-api

We're trying to know when a message has been truly sent, and the gmail API seems to provide this information indirectly, via the user history, when the message is labeled SENT.

There's a problem, though, when the user has the UNDO feature enabled: The message is labelled SENT, event though the message has not really been sent. If you undo, the message has the SENT label removed and the DRAFT label added.

So far, we've been unable to find any "event" in the history that records the actual send happening.

We need to process a message that has been really sent, and to do it as soon as possible, avoiding, if possible, waiting the max undo time available today (30 seconds).

Any tip on how we can acomplish that? Anything we missed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

For example PHP code:

```
/**
* Send Message.
*
* @param Google_Service_Gmail $service Authorized Gmail API instance.
* @param string $userId User's email address. The special value 'me'
* can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
* @param Google_Service_Gmail_Message $message Message to send.
* @return Google_Service_Gmail_Message sent Message.
*/
function sendMessage($service, $userId, $message) {
try {
$message = $service->users_messages->send($userId, $message);
print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . ' sent.';
return $message;
} catch (Exception $e) {
print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

You can try can get the `$message->getId()` if null, it is not sent and if not null message has been sent.

```
if($message->getId() != null){
//message has been seent

your code
}
else{

//message not been sent

your code
}
```

Or try the [Advanced search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en), if both not working just stick on what you are currently doing because currently `User.history` do not have these features.

You can look in this link how he use the advance search to check if the [email is sent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31255636/5995040)
HTH